# How do I enable log_slow_queries on MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql

How do I enable log_slow_queries on MySQL 5.1? Im running redhat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by RedMumba, this is correct..

```
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_slow_queries

you might also want to consider how "slow" the queries are by seconds that you want to log
using

```
long_query_time = 1   # Log anything over 1 second..
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit /etc/my.cnf and add:

```
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
```

Where the value is equal to the log file to store the slow queries.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to define what a slow query time is, eg:
long_query_time = 5

Both this and log_slow_queries should be in the [mysqld] section.